# How to compare first letter of a word with other char both defined in macros (case-insensitively)?

Tags: expansion, comparison

The following MWE shows that how I get the first letter of a word and compare it with other character both defined in macros. 
In my case I need to perform it case-insensitively so I used `\uppercase` to make both characters uppercase; the latter one is uppercase too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\firstletter#1{\expandafter\justfirst#1\relax}
\def\justfirst#1#2\relax{#1}

\begin{document}
    \def\data{abcde}
    \uppercase{\edef\letter{\firstletter{\data}}}%
    \def\A{A}
    \ifx\A\letter Equal\else Not Equal\fi
\end{document}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work as I was expected! (getting `Equal` not `Not Equal`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\uppercase` doesn't expand the contents of its argument, so there's nothing there to be uppercased as far as it is concerned.

A couple of various possibilities to fix it:

```
\edef\letter{\firstletter{\data}}% 
\uppercase\expandafter{\expandafter\edef\expandafter\letter\expandafter{\letter}}%
```

Or:

```
\edef\tmpa{\uppercase{\edef\noexpand\letter{\firstletter{\data}}}}%
\tmpa
```

There are probably other alternatives as well.

Comment: Thanks, but why can't we use something like \edef\letter{\uppercase{\edef\noexpand\letter{\firstletter{\data}}}}?
I mean without using any temporary macro, just expanding the original one.

Comment: @javadr — write `\show\letter` to see why. `\uppercase` doesn't expand, so the temporary macro needs to be executed for `\uppercase` to finally perform its duty.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only string data (all macros to be tested expand to characters), you can do by switching arguments around. This assumes the first argument to `\firstletterequalTF` does not expand to an empty list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstletterequalTF}[2]{% both can be macros
  \expandafter\fle@i#1\@nil{#2}%
}
\def\fle@i#1#2\@nil#3{%
  \expandafter\fle@ii\expandafter{#3}{#1}%
}
\def\fle@ii#1#2{%
  \uppercase{\if#1#2}%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\dataa{abcde}
\newcommand\dataA{Abcde}
\newcommand\datab{bcde}
\newcommand\fixedA{A}

\begin{document}

\firstletterequalTF{abcde}{A}{Equal}{Not Equal} /
\firstletterequalTF{\dataa}{A}{Equal}{Not Equal} /
\firstletterequalTF{abcde}{\fixedA}{Equal}{Not Equal} /
\firstletterequalTF{\dataa}{\fixedA}{Equal}{Not Equal}

\firstletterequalTF{\dataA}{\fixedA}{Equal}{Not Equal}

\firstletterequalTF{\datab}{\fixedA}{Equal}{Not Equal}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An implementation in `expl3`, where the ability to expandably compare strings is exploited, note the last command that shows that, contrary to macros using `\uppercase`, the function is expandable. Empty strings are not of a concern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \javadr_firstletterequal:nn { T,F,TF,p }
 {
  % compare the two strings after full expansion:
  % extract the first item from the the first string and uppercase it;
  % uppercase the second string; f expansion is used so using explicit
  % strings or macros is the same
  \str_if_eq_x:nnTF
   { \str_upper_case:f { \str_head:f { #1 } } }
   { \str_upper_case:f { #2 } }
   { \prg_return_true: }
   { \prg_return_false: }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_head:n { f }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\firstletterequalTF}{mmmm}
 {
  \javadr_firstletterequal:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\dataa{abcde}
\newcommand\dataA{Abcde}
\newcommand\datab{bcde}
\newcommand\fixedA{A}

\begin{document}

\firstletterequalTF{abcde}{A}{Equal}{Not Equal} /
\firstletterequalTF{\dataa}{A}{Equal}{Not Equal} /
\firstletterequalTF{abcde}{\fixedA}{Equal}{Not Equal} /
\firstletterequalTF{\dataa}{\fixedA}{Equal}{Not Equal}

\firstletterequalTF{\dataA}{\fixedA}{Equal}{Not Equal}

\firstletterequalTF{\datab}{\fixedA}{Equal}{Not Equal}

\firstletterequalTF{}{}{Equal}{Not Equal}

\firstletterequalTF{}{\fixedA}{Equal}{Not Equal}

\edef\test{%
  \firstletterequalTF{\dataa}{\fixedA}{Equal}{Not Equal}%
}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]